# consecutive copying of text fragments in emacs

Tags: emacs

I want as I search backwards in the document to do copying (M-x) and then return to the saved mark after a few copying commands and paste the things I copied. What ways are there to do this?

Best,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean you want to paste all of the things you copied in a single go?

One way is to do the first copy via <kbd>M-w</kbd> (aka <kbd>M-x kill-ring-save</kbd>), and the subsequent copies using <kbd>C_M-w M-w</kbd>.  You can read about that [in the docs here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Appending-Kills).

If you want to paste the chunks you copied individually, you can cycle through the pastes by doing <kbd>C-y M-y M-y ...</kbd>, where each successive <kbd>M-y</kbd> replaces the previous yank with the prior entry in the [kill ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Internals-of-Kill-Ring.html).

One nice mode for choosing which element from the kill ring to paste is the [BrowseKillRing](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing) package.

Comment: from the link you put up there a link to: "Yanking Earlier Kills" in sec13.3 of the docs explains the C-y M-y... command

Comment: how can you set the pointer in the kill ring back to the begining without having to cycle through all over again?

Comment: @Vass I don't know an easy way to reset the kill ring as the `C-y M-y M-y` sequence uses the state of the kill ring to decide what to yank next and it modifies the kill ring.  You'd have to write a replacement for `M-y` which operates on a copy of the kill ring, and have `C-y` re-initialize that copy of the kill ring.  Or something along those lines.  That's worth another question if you want that behavior - someone will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you want random (i.e., direct) access to any entry in the kill ring.

In **Icicles** you can see all of your `kill-ring`, filter it dynamically to see only some of it, and yank any entries from it using completion. By default, <kbd>C-y</kbd> is bound in *Icicle* mode to `icicle-yank-maybe-completing`.

That's the same as `yank`, unless you give it a negative prefix arg (e.g., <kbd>C--</kbd>).  In that case, it lets you complete against the `kill-ring`.  Completion can be prefix, apropos (substring, regexp), or fuzzy.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands